# How to reduce gap between Stars in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to reduce gap between stars but no luck.

Code below for your ref

```
 <MuiThemeProvider  >
                            <Rating
                                onChange={() => console.log('onChange')}
                                value={4}
                                max={5}
                                iconFilled={<ToggleStar  color={colors.green500} />}
                                iconHovered={<ToggleStarBorder  color={colors.green500} />}
                                iconNormal ={<ToggleStarBorder color={colors.black300}/>}
                                className={classes.Rating}
                                 spacing ={0}
                                onChange={(value) => console.log(`Rated with value ${value}`)}
                              />
                        </MuiThemeProvider >
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `itemStyle` and `itemIconStyle` props:

```
const smallDistanceStyle = {
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  padding: 5
}

const iconStyle = {
   width: ...,
   height: ...
}

<Rating
  itemStyle={smallDistanceStyle}
  itemIconStyle={iconStyle}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: bro i want star on center please can you help me

Comment: try to play with `itemIconStyle` a bit, I'm not sure what, maybe proper width and height setting is the solution. I extended my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I found that

```
<Rating
      value={5}
      readOnly
      sx={{
        fontSize: "5rem",
        "& .MuiRating-icon": {
            width: '4.5rem'
        }
      }}
      icon={<StarRateIcon fontSize="5rem" sx={{ color: "black" }} />}
/>
```

worked for me. It was able to bring the stars a little closer together.